# Access Knockout Js object data

Tags: object, knockout.js

I have the following knockout js object. I want to compare the `booking_time` value alone in `.phtml` file. How to access the value.

```js
[
  {
    "item_id": "204",
    "name": "Sample Name",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": "600.0000",
    "booking_time": "Hourly",
  }
]
```

I am trying with the below code, so I can get the above result. But I need `booking_time` value alone to compare.

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(getBookingtime(), null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Why don't you give a name to that object and reference it in the html file?

Comment: You can't access it in the html without giving a name to it

Answer (score 0):

in your model:

```
this.items = [
  {
    "item_id": "204",
    "name": "Sample Name",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": "600.0000",
    "booking_time": "Hourly",
  }
]
```

in html

```
<!--ko foreach: items-->
    <!--ko if: booking_time === 'Hourly' -->
    <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```